# Evaluating an integral Mathematica doesn't know

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have an integral neither *Mathematica* nor Maple can evaluate. Would you please suggest me a solution?

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 + q^2/((1 - b/r)^alpha*r^4)]*(1 - b/r)^alpha*r^2, r]
```

Comment: 1) What are the constraints on the parameters (`q`, `b`, etc)? Are they `Real`, `> 0` etc.? 2) Are you sure that an analytical integral even exists?

Comment: What is `alpha`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: first thing i do with something like this is try with specific numeric (rational) values for all the parameters.  There is an analytic result for `alpha=2` but otherwise you are sol.

Comment: I suggest browsing the math.stackexchange.com community for the [integration](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration?sort=votes&pageSize=15) tag.  You may even want to post your question there-- the integration gurus on that site may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Re corey979: Really all constants are real number, by they can be positive or negative values, but r is positive and real. I think this integral should solve analytically, that is why I am asking here!

Comment: Re  george2079: Thank you for your kind help. I agree with you, but as checked, by changing the value of power (alpha), the solution changes without any logical process and it is hard to find a general solution according to those solutions.

Answer (score 3):

For the simple case of `alpha -> 0`

```
expr0 = Sqrt[1 + q^2/((1 - b/r)^alpha*r^4)]*(1 - b/r)^alpha*r^2 /. 
   alpha -> 0;

assume0 = FunctionDomain[expr0, r]

(*  r != 0 && q^2 + r^4 >= 0  *)

sol0 = Assuming[assume0, Integrate[expr0, r] // FullSimplify]

*  (q^2*r + r^5 - 
      2*q*Sqrt[I*q*(q^2 + r^4)]*
        EllipticF[I*ArcSinh[Sqrt[I/q]*
                r], -1])/(3*Sqrt[q^2 + r^4])  *)
```

Looking at the case suggested by @george2079, i.e., `alpha -> 2`

```
expr2 = Sqrt[1 + q^2/((1 - b/r)^alpha*r^4)]*(1 - b/r)^alpha*r^2 /. alpha -> 2;
```

For `expr2` to be real

```
assume2 = FunctionDomain[expr2, r]

(*  r != 0 && b - r != 0 && q^2 + b^2 r^2 - 2 b r^3 + r^4 >= 0  *)

(sol2 = Assuming[assume2, Integrate[expr2, r] // Simplify]); // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {88.8856, Null}  *)
```

Display of the result is suppressed because it is quite long

```
LeafCount[sol2]

(*  3319  *)
```

Looking also at the case for `alpha -> 4`

```
expr4 = Sqrt[1 + q^2/((1 - b/r)^alpha*r^4)]*(1 - b/r)^alpha*r^2 /. alpha -> 4;
```

For `expr4` to be real

```
assume4 = FunctionDomain[expr4, r]

(*  r != 0 && b - r != 0 && b^4 + q^2 - 4 b^3 r + 6 b^2 r^2 - 4 b r^3 + r^4 >= 0  *)

(sol4 = Assuming[assume4, Integrate[expr4, r] // Simplify]); // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {15.3896, Null}  *)
```

Again, display of the result is suppressed because it is quite long--although much shorter than `sol2`

```
LeafCount[sol4]

(*  807  *)
```

Comment: Re  Bob Hanlon: Thank you very much for your kind assistance. Really, I know that when alpha is a number this integral can be solved, but I need the solution in general case for alpha. Would you please help me?